# Free Json validator for draft 07

Tags: .net, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Does anyone know of a free JSON schema validator that supports JSON schema draft-07 (draft-06 would also work I think). Also it has to work on .NET 4.0

Specifically I am looking for a dll I can add to my .NET project that will allow me to check my response is valid against a schema (this allows me to check I haven't accidentally made my response invalid for the schema).

I have looked online and can't find anything that matches these requirements. I have tried:

- [Json.NET Schema (Newtonsoft)](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) -> Not free
- [NJsonSchema](https://github.com/RSuter/NJsonSchema) -> only supports draft-04
- [Manatee Json](https://github.com/gregsdennis/Manatee.Json) -> does not support .NET 4.0

NJsonSchema comes the closest to my requirements, but as it only support draft-04 it lacks support for the `"const"` keyword used in my schemas.

Comment: Newtonsoft has a free tier which supports 1k validations per hour. If you need this for commercial purposes, try it, then buy a licence? I don't think what you're looking for exists. As an aside, Stackoverflow is not designed for asking "recomend me a library" type questions, and this question will probably get deleted. You should ask such questions on forums or chat systems (there's a JSON Schema slack) - The JSON Schema site lists implementations, but none that meet your requirements. Sorry.

Comment: Is upgrading to .Net 4.5 not an option?  The transition from 4.0 is pretty seamless.

Comment: @gregsdennis thanks for the suggestion, at the time this wasn't an option. However in addition to other reasons that will be the way I'm going to go, once I have time to get round to it! Thanks.